# Floating point assembly on intel processor

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, fpu, x87

I have been studying how floating point operations are performed on a 32 bit intel machine. I have disassembled the following lines of C code to obtain how the compiler translates these lines on assembly.

```
a = 13;
b = 5;
d = (float) a / (float) b;
```

And here is the disassembled version of the code shown above:

```
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],0xd
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],0x5
fild   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
fild   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14]
fdivrp st(1),st
fstp   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x18]
```

What I find confusing is the fdivrp and fstp instructions. From what I read the code above will store the result of the floating point division on the st(1) register, and then pop the top of stack making st(1) the top and not st(0). However the next fstp instruction stores the contents of st(0) to the memory location pointed by the address ebp-0x18 and then pops the stack making st(1) the top. I believe I have misunderstood the documents on how these instructions operate as my understanding will not store the result in memory. I would be grateful if someone can please explain how exactly these 2 instructions operate.

Comment: The top of the stack is always called st(0).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has a link to http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html, which should cover everything.  Unless you have to deal with x87 code often, I'd recommend not spending time on it except when it comes up in practice.  x87 is obsolete, except that the 32bit ABI still returns FP values in `st(0)`.  The 64bit ABI uses SSE registers to pass/return floats and doubles.  32bit code can be compiled to use SSE/SSE2, if you don't mind breaking compatibility with 13-year-old hardware (AMD Athlon XP was the last CPU to not have SSE2).

Comment: Peter, I see you refer to the 32 bit ABI and 64 bit ABI regularly. Please be aware that there are different ABIs for different OSes, and it is not quite clear which one you mean, Probably Linux or BDS? Note that in 32 bit Windows, x87 code is not so obsolete at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point registers are always addressed relative to the current stack top. Thus, `st(0)` is always the stack top. The `fdivrp st(1), st` places the result in `st(1)` and then immediately pops `st(0)` so the stack only holds a single item, which is the new `st(0)` containing the result. The `fstp` writes it to memory and removes it from the fpu stack, leaving it empty.

Comment: Does that mean that fdivrp st(1), st pops st1 to st0? The documents states that to pop the register stack, the processor marks the ST(0) register as empty and increments the stack pointer (TOP) by 1. I find that phrase difficult to understand.

Comment: By popping, the stack `TOP` changes, and since register indexing is relative to `TOP`, the physical register that was previously called `st(1)` becomes `st(0)`. There is no data movement involved.